# How to only generate one file and its map with webpack and nothing else

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a react application, and I want to bundle the `entry` file into a single output file. This works fine with the following `entry/output` config for webpack:

```
{
  "entry": [ "/path/to/file/src/index.js" ],
  "output": {
      "path": "/path/to/file/build",
      "pathinfo": false,
      "filename": "my-app.js",
      "futureEmitAssets": true,
      "chunkFilename": "[name].chunk.js",
      "publicPath": "/"
  }
}
```

but the output of `build` contains

```
➜ ls -al build
index.html
my-app.js
my-app.js.map
precache-manifest.80798dd0fbc0ae8659c760ea32cca65d.js
service-worker.js
```

I just want to see `my-app.js` and `my-app.js.map` and nothing else. How do I do this?

Comment: Seems like this should not happen. I'm assuming you deleted those files and ran webpack again and it re-creates them?

Comment: @ToddChaffee, yes I am running `rm -rf build && npm run build && ls -al build` here and that's the output I get

Comment: Could you add your `package.json` file to your question? There might be something in there that is creating those files as part of the build.

Comment: Can you add the whole `webpack.config.js`? It seems there are plugins configured here. For example, it seems `index.html` is being created by the `HtmlWebpackPlugin`.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using `clean-webpack-plugin`

```
config.plugins.push(new CleanWebpackPlugin({
  cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: [
    path.join(process.cwd(), 'build/service-worker.js'),
    path.join(process.cwd(), 'build/precache-manifest*.js'),
    path.join(process.cwd(), 'build/index.html'),
  ],
}));
```

Comment: That works, but it seems like a bit of a band-aid. I'm curious how those files are getting created in the first place.

Comment: @ToddChaffee this is a create-react-app project output project.

Comment: Did you use `npm run eject` in order to be able to edit the config files?